# Pandas not sorting properly

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort a dataframe by date.
This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns = ['time', 'consumption'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))
df = df.sort('time')
```

Output:

```
                 time consumption
time
2016-12-09 2016-12-09  23:00,0.37
2016-12-09 2016-12-09  22:00,0.78
2016-12-10 2016-12-10   0:00,0.24
2016-12-10 2016-12-10   3:00,0.23
2016-12-10 2016-12-10   4:00,0.26
```

Column Time is not sorted properly.

What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry you've failed to explain why you think this behaviour is incorrect, what's the desired output here? Note that year first date strings will by default use format `%Y-%d-%m` is why you think it's incorrect? If so, you want `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`, and you don't need this: `df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))`, you want `df = df.set_index(df['time'])`

Comment: Sorry why is it not sorted properly? What should the desired df look like? What is your raw data, and code to create this df?